# struts action when I click on image

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a jsp page which contains images and when I click on theat image it should go to other jsp page.How to do this in struts2.It was working fine before I add the image action.

Login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="login" method="post">  
<s:textfield name="id" label="Employee Id"></s:textfield>  
<s:textfield name="name" label="Employee Name"></s:textfield>
<s:submit value="save"></s:submit>   
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginAction.java:

```
package login;

public class LoginAction {

    private int id;  
    private String name;  

    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  

    public String getName() {  
   return name;  
    }  

    public String execute(){  
        return "success";
}
}
```

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0.//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="login" extends="struts-default" namespace="/" >
   <default-action-ref name="upload" />



   <action name="login" class="login.LoginAction" method="execute">  
<result name="success">products.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="click" class="login.ItemAction" method="execute">
<result name="success">productdetails.jsp</result>
</action>

   </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>dhanya</display-name>


   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>

    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>


   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>



     <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
```

Products.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>product images</title>

</head>
 <div align="center" style="white-space: nowrap;word-wrap:break-word;">
   <%@ include file="Header.jsp" %>

   </div>
<body>

<a href="<s:url action="click"/>"></a><img src="images/bp.jpg" class="tooltip" title="BP monitor" id="BP monitor"> </a>
<a href="<s:url action="click"/>">"><img src="images/sethescope.jpg" class="tooltip" title="sethescope" id="sethescope"></a>

    </body>
    <div align="center" style="white-space: nowrap;word-wrap:break-word;">
   <%@ include file="Footer.jsp" %>

   </div>

</html>
```

ItemAction.java

```
package login;

public class ItemAction {   
    public String execute(){  
            return "success";
    }   

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want an image associated with an anchor, you can do it as follows:

```
<s:url var='imageUrl' action='yourActionName'/>
<s:a href='%{#imageUrl}'><img src='<s:url value="images/yourimage.jpg"/>'/></s:a>
```

You'll notice that I construct a named URL, reference the named URL in the href attribute of the Struts2 anchor tag and I use an inline URL to reference the correct context-based path to the image to display.

To your question however, it looks like you have a stray `</a>` in the first image link you included in your `products.jsp`.

Comment: I need it like,I have two images in products.jsp page,and when I click on one image ,it should go to other jsp page.how the action call for this in struts2

Comment: can somebody help me to do this ,,it is very urgent

Answer (score 0):

well first you define action in `strtus.xml` file and prespect to that action class and we can call action using this way.

**Products.jsp**

```
 <a href="<s:url action="cancel.action" />"><img src="image/1.png" class="tooltip" height="42" width="42" title="BP monitor" id="BP monitor" > </a>

 <a href="<s:url action="hello.action"/>"><img src="image/2.jpg" height="42" width="42" class="tooltip" title="sethescope" id="sethescope"></a>
```

and in strtus.xml

```
<action name="cancel" 
        class="com.test.CancelAction" 
        method="execute">
        <result name="success">/Cancel.jsp</result>
  </action>

   <action name="hello" 
        class="com.test.ApproveAction" 
        method="execute">
        <result name="success">/Approve.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

and define classes  which i have defined on `XML` file with return Sucess message and check .it will work for sure . Sorry i have taken some other images for test purpose . Thanks and for any doubt ask here .

Change `<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>` to `<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>` in strtus.xml

Comment: :still it is not working.I'm getting the below errors:SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/Users/RajD/Documents/java/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/dhanya/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:19:26

Comment: @DhanyaRaj i have updated the answer to change filter URL in Strtus.xml  check updated URL in my post .